# mixed model variance-covariance matrix| parameter estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, glmm, unbiased-estimator, reml

I am fairly new to LMM's and I am trying to undestand how the parameter estimation happens;
According to this:
[image]

Beta is obtained with equation 13.28. Beta is supposed to be the parameters for the fixed effects, X stands here for the design matrix for the fixed effects V is the variance-covariance matrix and y is the response value.

However, I don't understand how to obtain matrix V and the book I am using "linear mixed effect models using R by Galecki and Burzykowski is not really clear in it either).

I have tried obtaining the matrix V in R with the following command Cov(Y, X), This returns a vector of 1x7 (which makes sense I have 7 fixed variables; but with this I cannot calculate Beta since  V is supposed to be a square matrix.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it helps to consider what dimension the matrix $V_i^{-1}$ needs to have so that the given matrix products are defined. You'll find that it needs to be a square matrix of dimension $n_i \times n_i$, where $n_i$ is the length of the vector $y_i$ (as well as the number of rows of $X_i$). In the book's nomenclature, $y_i$ is the vector of observations in some group $i$. Therefore, it becomes clear that $V_i$ has to be the VCV-matrix of responses in group $i$, $y_i$. (Side note: the estimator in (13.28) is of the form $(X'W^{-1}X')^{-1}X'W^{-1}y$, which would be the Generalized Least Squares (GLS) estimator for $\beta$, if the response $y$ were known to have the VCV-matrix $W$. It is not exactly the GLS estimator, because the VCV-matrix does actually depend on an unknown parameter $\theta$ which has to be estimated.)

This might already help you figure out what matrix V should look like! But the answer is actually also in the book.

---

Spoiler alert: from (13.25) and (13.26) of the book, you see that
$$V_i = \sigma^2(Z_iDZ_i' + R_i),$$
where $Z_i$ is the matrix of regressors for the random effects of group $i$, $D$ is the VCV matrix of random effects, $R_i$ is the correlation matrix of the residuals in group $i$, and $\sigma^2$ is the residual variance. You'll obtain the whole matrix $V$ as a block diagonal matrix with the matrices $V_i$ on the diagonal.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, however some parts that remain vague; you mentioned that σ^2 is the residual variance, In my own data (simulated), I did not add noise hence this is missing and so is R; so than V = ZDZ` ? furthermore  the obtained  VCV matrix V  in my case is square but not a block diagonal..: Here below I will outline what I did to calculate this in R: first I calculated the matrix D simply by calling the cov function on the design matrix for random effects -> cov(Z); note that Z is 45x 15. This in turn gives me a square matrix of 15 x 15. I than obtain V  with V= ZDZ'

Comment: Without further code it is difficult to assess the problems. But I can already tell you one important mistake: D is not equal to cov(Z)! D is a (typically unknown) VCV matrix that specifies the covariance of random effects in the population of groups. It is estimated from the data, and has relatively little to do with Z (although I guess that the estimator for D will in some complicated way depend on Z)

Comment: Lukas, Thank you for your feedback. I did assume that COV(Z) would result in matrix D. Can you elaborate on how matrix D is obtained?

Comment: Estimating matrix D is (IMHO) the central challenge in LMM, and how exactly this works is out of scope for a comment. The book you are already reading should help you further on this. Roughly, all algorithms work by parameterizing D in terms of some parameter, and then maximizing the likelihood (ML) or the restricted likelihood (REML) by means of some optimization algorithm.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your comments Lukas, really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. Please consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer if you found it useful!